# Refreshing url by vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, refresh, reload, inertiajs

I refresh my page via `window.location.reload` and `setTimeout`. It works fine, but when I change a URL, the reload function ticks one last time in a another page.

Any idea how to fix it?

```html
<script setup>
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
</script>

<template>

...content

</template>


<script>
    methods: {
        reloadPage() {
            window.location.reload();
        },
        reload() {
            setTimeout(this.reloadPage, 10000);
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.reload();
    },
    Unmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.reload());
    }

};
</script>
```

Comment: i dont understand. what is the issue? also, what is the objective of reloading the page? just to reload it? or are you reloading it to solve some extrange behavior in your code?

Comment: Please describe the desired behaviour and current actual behaviour before showing code.

Comment: you forced the script to execute the reloadPage() method in 10 secs. In that method you simply reload. If you add a conditional check in this method if the reload should really happen (like checking the current url) you could reload the location based on that conditional check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started using vue.js recently, so bear with me. I think you need to pass the `timeoutId` into `clearTimeout`. Since you haven't done that, setTimeout() is running even after the component has been unmounted.

This should work for you!

Edit: Kissu, why did you delete my answer, rewrite it, and then claim an edit? Reported.

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    timeoutId: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    reloadPage() {
      window.location.reload();
    },
    reload() {
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(this.reloadPage, 10000);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.reload();
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That found :) Just a little correction. I must change
Unmount()
to
beforeUnmount()
have a nice day